# jQuery class increment on divs

Tags: jquery

I have 4 tabbed content boxes, each with anywhere from 1 to 6 divs within like so:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
   <div class="tabbedProduct">
   </div>
   <div class="tabbedProduct">
   </div>
   <div class="tabbedProduct">
   </div>
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
   <div class="tabbedProduct">
   </div>
   <div class="tabbedProduct">
   </div>
   <div class="tabbedProduct">
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm then using jQuery to add an incremental number to each **.tabbedProduct** div within the **.tab-content** div so for instance:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
   <div class="tabbedProduct item1">
   </div>
   <div class="tabbedProduct item2">
   </div>
   <div class="tabbedProduct item3">
   </div>
</div>
```

Of course I need the counters to start from 1 within each **.tab-content** div so in this instance the .tab-content div with the id of #tab-1 would count to **.tabbedProduct item3** by the end.

My issue is, that the jQuery I have is continuing to count through the other **.tab-content** divs and so in the above instance the first **.tabbedProduct** div would have a item4 added but I need the counter to start again so it would be item1 to item 3 as per the first.

Here is the jQuery I have if anyone can help thanks very much.

```
$('.tab-content .tabbedProduct').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('item' + (i+1));
});
```

Happy New Year BTW :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.tab-content').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.tabbedProduct').each(function(el) {
    $(this).addClass('item' + (el + 1));
  });
});
```

You need to iterate across `.tab-content` and inside that iterate among `.tabbedProduct` and add the class, this way `el` will always initiate with 0 again for every `.tab-content`.

Comment: 14 secs before...I'll give it to you...but you should fix `el`, should be `i` (or vice versa)

Comment: Wow you guys are supper fast and super ace, within 3mins and I have a perfect answer! I tried to accept but have to wait 9mins.

Can I please just ask what the el is for, and can you basically use anything in there like (pi) so long as the reference below +1 is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Should be straight forward with a callback and `index`

```
$('.tabbedProduct').addClass(function() {
    return 'item' + ($(this).index()+1);
});
```